# top / htop; group process by command

Tags: linux, top, xubuntu, htop

I'd like to know how much resource a specific command is using.

`top` and `htop` displays information on per process basis but I'd like the information to be shown on per command basis. E.g. I'd like to know how much RAM chrome is using.

Comment: Utilities such as `top` and `ps` vary by OS. You should tag the question with the OS you are using.

Comment: No, but it may be coming: [#301](https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/301), [#920](https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/920),

Answer (score 31):

Pressing `H` in `htop` group the processes by the main thread (command), actually it toggles the threads visibility.

Comment: It does hide the threads, although there can still be a tree of processes. Using tree view and collapsing the trees with `F6` works to show only the process group, but sorting disables tree view.

Comment: I realised that in tree view, even with tree branches collapsed, it still doesn't show the totals, it's just per-process. There are columns that are supposed to list totals for children, but those don't seem to work, either. `htop` will not show totals no matter what you do.

Comment: Partially useful, but doesn't seem to really hide all the different entries when you scroll down.

Comment: This doesn't seem to provide cumulative resources usage.

Answer (score 21):

This is possible in `atop`. Just press `p` when running it. From the help:

```
Accumulated figures:
        'u'  - total resource consumption per user
        'p'  - total resource consumption per program (i.e. same process name)
        'j'  - total resource consumption per container
```

Comment: Only thing stopping me from using `atop` is the cron dependency, but there's an open [PR](https://github.com/Atoptool/atop/pull/55) that will hopefully fix that

Comment: Update: the PR was accepted, and a new `atop` version will be released with no `cron` dependency.

Comment: This might not give the correct result for many commands. For instance, `firefox` launches many `Web Content` processes (https://superuser.com/questions/1299746/whats-web-content-in-top-doing-taking-up-memory), and these would show separately. There is no a priori way to tell which to sum.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio that's true. You also won't see the resource usage of child processes launched by a `xargs` command, for that matter. Getting statistics about all child processes is somewhat tedious, although possible by following the breadcrumbs in [procfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html).

Comment: So there are at least two sets of processes that are not counted in the total sum.
If I get it right, neither the top voted answer or this one really provide the result sought by the OP, they would actually provide a figure closer to the actual target than a "simple look".
See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364106/226614).

Answer (score 12):

You could run `top` in batch mode `-b` with 1 iteration `-n1`. You grep it, pipe it to `awk`, `SUM` the result and print it.

```
top -b -n1 | grep chrome | awk '{ SUM += $9} END { print SUM }'
```

I don't know which column you want to output. Change `$9` to fit your needs.

Comment: What about converting to human readable format?

Comment: This might not give the correct result for many commands. For instance, `firefox` launches many `Web Content` processes, that would not enter the sum (https://superuser.com/questions/1299746/whats-web-content-in-top-doing-taking-up-memory).
`ps -eo <several column identifiers>,command` instead of `top -b -n1` could fix this problem.

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364106/226614).